# Zip all (original) images from media gallery

Tags: functions, images, uploads, media, backup

I like to know if there is already a solution or workaround to zip all images which were uploaded to a WordPress installation. (But only the original images, not the thumbnails.)

Are there internal functions or maybe OS shell scripts? If not, what is the best way to generate such zip-file? Parse all upload-dirs recursively an zip, if the filename doesn't have a thumbnail pattern? Or better grab image list from database and then zip this list?

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do it manually. By FTP just download the **wp-content/uploads** directory. If you want to automate this and the media files zip here is a plugin-

[downML - Download Media Library](https://wordpress.org/plugins/downml/)

But it's not updated for more than 2 years. So you have to test it before use it on live site.

There is another solution in my mind. If you can find a **PHP Script** to zip images from **URL** you can use this below code to get all the images URLs and create a zip from them. But this script will not very memory friendly.

All images URL code-

```
$query_images_args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'post_status'    => 'inherit',
    'posts_per_page' => - 1,
);

$query_images = new WP_Query( $query_images_args );

$images = array();
foreach ( $query_images->posts as $image ) {
    $images[] = wp_get_attachment_url( $image->ID );
}
```

Now you'll get all the images URLs in `$images`.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'll take your wordpress query and combine it with a shell script. My aim is to have a script which runs once a day via cronjob, to serve my users a daily "fresh" archive with all images.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-an-off-site-backup-of-your-site-with-rsync-on-centos-6 I think this post can help you.